# Swift NSTimer only runs function once

Tags: function, swift, nstimer

So I have looked around, and I can't find what I am doing wrong, I am running Swift 1.2, and using SpriteKit by the way.

```
//showing you just in case
import SpriteKit

//My variables
var countDownLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AmericanTypewriter-Light")
var time = 4
var timer = NSTimer()

//Don't want to give you my entire project, I know I can't override a function outside of its class 
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) { 
    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if playButton.containsPoint(location) {

//I want this to run 4 times, but is only running once
            func countdown() {
                time--
                    countDownLabel.text = "\(time)"
            }       

//This is set to run my function every second for ever.
         timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector(countdown()), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

            playButton.removeFromParent()

            countDownLabel.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
            countDownLabel.fontSize = 70
            self.addChild(countDownLabel)   
        }  
    }
```

I want my function countdown to run 4 times, but It is only running once for some reason, even though its set to run forever, I am also not getting any error or warnings, sorry if obvious, and if code is hard to understand, I just included the function it was all in.

Comment: Actually the timer is _never_ running. The part of your code that creates the timer is never being executed. If it were executed. the timer would run and your app would crash because its selector is not valid.

Comment: Yup, thats why I did change it to that, makes sense now, I wasn't really sure, and couldn't find it, so I changed it tell I stopped getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Selector(countdown())' is evaluated to nil. So,

1.Move 'countdown' function to outside of touchesBegin.

2.Use 'selector: "countdown"' instead of 'Selector(countdown())'

3.Invalidate your timer after called four times.

```
var time = 4
var timer = NSTimer()

func countdown() {
    if --time == 0 { timer.invalidate() }
    println( "\(time)" )
}       

func X() {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval( 1, target: self, selector: "countdown", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```